# Get all text in a bounding rectangle

Tags: javascript, html

I made a region selector tool which makes a rectangle on the screen and gives the coordinates (top, left, width and height). Basically I want to get all (and only) visible text inside that rectangle. Also it should be the exact text, no repetitions.

This is how I make the region:

[image]

I'm trying something like this:

```
            var top = parseInt($('#selectionn33').css('top')) 
            var left = parseInt($('#selectionn33').css('left')) 
            var width = parseInt($('#selectionn33').css('width')) 
            var height = parseInt($('#selectionn33').css('height')) 

            var items = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
            for (var i = items.length; i--;) 
            {
                var rect = items[i].getBoundingClientRect();
                if(rect.top >= top && rect.top <= (top + height))
                {
                    if(rect.left >= left && rect.left <= (left + width))
                    {
                        console.log(items[i].textContent);
                    }
                }
            }
```

But it gets a lot of text I don't want, like text that is from an element that meets the criteria but is outside the rectangle.

Any ideas how I can make this?

Comment: If you use a fixed width font of a known size, could you trim the characters out of the text that don't fall within your rectangle after getting all the text?

Comment: There's definitely no easy way to do this. My best suggestion is to use `Range.getBoundingClientRect()` and iteratively set the start and end of the range, testing as you go. This is going to get ugly - and slow - very quickly, but it should be possible.

Comment: How does an element meet the criteria but is outside the rectangle? Do you want to crop each line of text based on the selection borders? Or only elements that fit entirely in the selection? How do you want the text organised, after it collects text from multiple elements? Can you maybe upload an image, detailing the expected behaviour?

Comment: Sure, as you can see by the following image, I made a rectangle region selector tool. I want to get all the text inside that rectangle. http://i.imgur.com/oT0MwPC.jpg

Comment: I would go with what @nrabinowitz told you, maybe in conjunction with [Range.caretRangeFromPoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/caretRangeFromPoint) you could achieve something not so ugly, but still heavy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get elements that are entirely inside the selection, as described in your comment, with very little changes to your code. Basically you are getting elements which have the top left corner within the selection. You need to make sure the bottom right corner is also inside the selection:

```
var $selection = $('#selection33');
var top = parseInt($selection.css('top')); 
var left = parseInt($selection.css('left')); 
var right = left + parseInt($selection.css('width')); 
var bottom = top + parseInt($selection.css('height')); 

var items = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
for (var i = items.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  var rect = items[i].getBoundingClientRect();
  if(
    rect.top >= top && rect.bottom <= bottom &&
    rect.left >= left && rect.right <= right
  ) {
       try
       {
           found = items[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
       }
           catch(err)
       {
           found = items[i].textContent;
       }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think that's better although I think it might miss some elements which might show text inside the rectangle but it's actual element is beyond it. Haven't encountered that yet though. This is happening though, if you look at the video, it's repeating text maybe because the parents count their children's text as theirs. http://tryna.get.a.handbeezy.com/2016-07-06_21-42-34.mp4

Comment: This is a very complex scenario, with lots of possibilities. You should really think about what you need, and update your question with more details.

Comment: That being said, you can include paddings in the calculations, to get elements that go outside selection, and check for nested elements to avoid duplication